# Prove that $a^{(p-1)/2} $$\equiv$-1 (modp). Deduce that if $a, b$ are primitive roots modp, then $a\times b$ is NOT a primitive root mod p.

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a$ be a primitive root mod the odd prime p.  Prove that $a^{(p-1)/2} $$\equiv$-1 (modp).  Deduce that if $a, b$ are primitive roots modp, then $a\times b$ is NOT a primitive root mod p.

Here we define that, $a$ is a primitive root of $n$ if $(a,n)=$1 and $a$ has order exactly $\phi(n)$  (where the order refers to the least such $k$ where $a^k$ $\equiv$ 1 (modn), $k \geq 1$) (and $\phi$ denotes Euler's totient function.)

I have started by noting that $a^{(p-1)/2}$ $\equiv \pm 1 $ mod $p$ by Fermats Little Theorem and equating $y=a^{(p-1)/2}$

Also Eulers criterion tells us that $(\frac{a}{p})$ is congruent to  $a^{(p-1)/2}$ mod p

Also, Legendre tells us that $(\frac{a}{p})$ =-1 if $a$ is a quadratic non-residue of $p$

So putting this together, am I to show that $a$ being a primitive root mod p implies that it is a quadratic non-residue mod p?

Can't quite get my head round this problem.  Help appreciated,  thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you mean $\frac{p-1} {2}$ as opposed to $p - \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, that was an oversight, thankyou

Answer (score 4):

The Legendre symbol is unimportant here.  $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv \pm 1$, and it's not $1$ since $a$ is a primitive root, so it's $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

[How to derive this expression $ r ^{ (p-1)/2} \equiv -1 \pmod p$ for primitive root of an odd prime $p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353741/how-to-derive-this-expression-r-p-1-2-equiv-1-pmod-p-for-primitive-r/353747#353747) Gives an answer for your first part. For the second part use the facts of first one i.e:

$a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1(\mod p) $ and $b^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1(\mod p)$

$(ab)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv1(\mod p) \implies ab$ $\text{is not the Primitive root of $p$}$

Answer (score 0):

Using Fermat's Little Theorem, $$a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$$

$\implies p$ divides $(a^{p-1}-1)\implies p$ divides $(a^{\frac{p-1}2}-1)(a^{\frac{p-1}2}+1)$

If $a$ is a primitive root, $ord_pa=p-1\implies a^r\not\equiv 1\pmod p$ for $r<p-1$

$\implies p$ does not divide $a^{\frac{p-1}2}-1$

$\implies p$  divides $a^{\frac{p-1}2}+1$

If $a,b$ are primitive roots $a^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv-1\pmod p$ and $b^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv-1\pmod p$

$\implies (ab)^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv(-1)^2\pmod p\equiv1$

So, $ord_p(ab)$ divides $\frac{p-1}2<p-1\implies ord_p(ab)<p-1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** For odd primes $p\geq 5$, $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is an integer $\geq 2$. If $a^{\frac{p-1}{2} } = 1 $, then $a$ is not a primitive root by definition.
Check $p=3$ and see if the statement holds.

**Hint 2:** $ab^{\frac{p-1}{2} } = a^{\frac{p-1}{2} } \times b^{\frac{p-1}{2} } $.